# Even though I use createPersistedState, the data is still lost when I refresh the page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I refresh the page, Vuex gets reset. Although the Vuex item in localStorage is not reset, when I check the Vue extension, the values are reset. The project breaks.
Package: vuex-persistedstate
Vue:2
Vuex:3

```
const modules = {
    x,
    y,
    z,
    g,
    h,
}


export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        environment : appConstants.environment,
        serviceUrl : appConstants.serviceUrl,
        aServiceUrl : appConstants.aServiceUrl,
        bServiceUrl : appConstants.bServiceUrl,
        cServiceUrl : appConstants.cServiceUrl,
    },
    mutations: {
        setServiceUrl(state, serviceUrl){
            state.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
        },
        setAServiceUrl(state, aServiceUrl){
            state.aServiceUrl = aServiceUrl;
        },
        setBServiceUrl(state, bServiceUrl){
            state.bServiceUrl = bServiceUrl;
        },
        setCServiceUrl(state, cServiceUrl){
            state.cServiceUrl = cServiceUrl;
        },
    },
    
    getters: {
        getServiceUrl: state => {
            return state.serviceUrl;
        },
        getAServiceUrl: state => {
            return state.aServiceUrl;
        },
        getBServiceUrl: state => {
            return state.bServiceUrl;
        },
        getCServiceUrl: state => {
            return state.cServiceUrl;
        },
    },
    modules: modules,
    plugins: [createPersistedState()],

})
```

Comment: This is specific to your case and needs a reproduction. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Obviously, if vuex-persistedstate unconditionally wouldn't work for everyone, it wouldn't exist in its current form

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same package, and it's working fine when passing a parameter to `createPersistedState()`

```
createPersistedState({
    paths: [
        'environment',
        'serviceUrl',
        'aServiceUrl'
    ],
    getState: (key) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
    setState: (key, state) => {
        Cookies.set(key, state, { expires: 100, secure: false })
    }
})
```

States that are not in the `paths` array will not be saved